# Stopping Visual Studio displaying debug info about web pages not in my solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I've started work on an ASP.Net project and for some reason Visual Studio keeps displaying what I assume is debug information about web pages I'm viewing (not from the web project) under a 'Script Documents' folder in the solution.

This is quite annoying as if I click on it accidentally it opens a long list files / messages / script blocking to do with gplus_notifications_gadget.html (part of the Google toobar, I think).
They disappear when I stop the web project, but I don't want them there in the first place.

Apart from getting rid of the Google toolbar, is there a way I can set Visual Studio not to pick up this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this, it seems that it's an issue that's been in since Visual Studio 2008.

[This blog post suggests several solutions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2009/04/06/disabling-script-debugging-in-vs-2008-ie8.aspx)

In the end, I settled for changing this registry key:

reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\AD7Metrics\Engine{F200A7E7-DEA5-11D0-B854-00A0244A1DE2} /v ProgramProvider /d {4FF9DEF4-8922-4D02-9379-3FFA64D1D639} /f

Answer (score 0):

The files under that "Script Documents" folder shows the output files generated by ASP.NET when you debug your website in Visual Studio. For example if you had a page called MyPage.aspx in your web project, opening it from under Script Documents would show you the resulting HTML that was produced from it. Therefore it can be quite useful to see what you end up with.

As far as I am aware there is no way to get rid of it and I don't think it is a real "folder" as such, it is just shown by Visual Studio during debugging.